# How to identify gold color in image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

I have an assignment regarding coin recognition. My country's coins consist of two colors: gold and silver. How do I identify the gold color?

I have managed crop each coin from images consist of few coins. I want to know how to identify gold color coin.

My lecturer suggested:

- Convert RGB to HSI
- Get the hue and saturation value of the cropped coin image
- If it's hue and saturation value in the range of gold's hue and
  saturation it is a gold coin.

My approach is the following:

1. Enhance the image so that the color the visible.
2. Identify each coin and crop them
3. Identify their color and split them into two groups: silver and gold.
4. Identify their value by making one coin from each color as reference then compare with the other coin with the reference coin (ratio based).

I have done step 1 and 2 but I'm stuck at the third step.  I have no idea how to differentiate between gold colored and silver colored coin. Which approach should I use to differentiate them in MATLAB?

[image: photo of coins]

Comment: um, the way you asked this the question is far too broad and can't be answered. Instead, **describe what *exactly* you're having problems with.**. I assume it's the first step. What research have you done regarding converting RGB to HSI image data with matlab? What of the results of your google/stackoverflow research did you not understand?

Comment: Ok Markus. I'm doing coin recognition system using matlab. Those are the example picture of my country's coin. I have to check the picture and calculate the total  value of coins in the picture. My approaches is 1.Enhance the image so that the color the visible.                              2.Than identify each coin and crop them                                               3. Then identify their color and split them into two group color silver and gold. 4 Then identify their value by making one coin from each color color

Comment: that explained exactly nothing with respect to the question I asked above: **Where are you stuck, exactly?** This is really no free code writing service, so you have to condense your problems down to a single, precise question, or else, we can't help you.

Comment: So given that photo I see some immediate problems with your approach, namely the 5 and 20 piece have a very similar colour. If you'd want to do this anyway, I'd suggest taking a set of photos from these coins, extract the average colour per coin, and using something like a [decision tree](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/classification-trees-and-regression-trees.html)

Comment: i stuck at 3 step.

Comment: So, where **exactly** are you stuck at step 3? Thiyraash, I'm about to give up in this question because you're really not doing much to even explain your problem. I will down vote this now. Please add all relevant info, including what your program can do up to now, and where exactly you need help, to the question, and not as a comment. Format properly. Ask a **single, precise** question (*not* "can anyone help me?").

Comment: Marcus i have update my question. Exactly where I'm stuck is what approaches should i used to differentiate the gold color and silver color. Sorry If I didn't give a clear explanation on where I'm stuck.

Comment: So, well, yes, how should we know based on what you tell us? Really, describe/show/illustrate the data you're looking at. Saying "my job is to tell gold from silver but I don't know how" doesn't describe what you're looking at exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's something to work with. It's only tuned for this particular image and it probably won't work for other images.

1. Perform a gamma correction with `gamma = 1.5`.  The reason why is because I want to bring the gold coins that are brighter on the right of the image down in intensity to match the gold coin on the left image so that it's easier to threshold and segment.
2. Use the hue and saturation channels to threshold out the gold coin.
3. Use morphology and fill in any holes that the thresholded result has
4. Remove any masses that have an area less than 12000 pixels.

---

## Step #1

You can perform gamma adjustment with [`imadjust`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imadjust.html) and with `gamma = 1.5`, you simply perform the following.  First load in the image which I'll do directly from StackOverflow, then gamma adjust:

```
close all;
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4FCV.jpg');
im_enhance = imadjust(im, [], [], 1.5);
```

`im` is the original image and `im_enhance` is the enhanced image.  We get the following enhanced image:

[image]

A little hard to see, but if you magnify the image yourself by clicking on the above image, you'll see that the gold colours on the right of the image are slightly darker than before.

## Step #2

First convert your image into HSV using [`rgb2hsv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html):

```
hsv = rgb2hsv(im2double(im_enhance));
```

After, I used [`impixelinfo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impixelinfo.html) with the above image open by doing `imshow(im_enhance)` and hovered my mouse over the gold coins to see what the hue and saturation were.  By inspection, I saw that the hue values were roughly 0.25 or less and the saturation values were 0.25 or greater to differentiate between the gold coins and silver coins.  Therefore, use these ranges to threshold and get a binary map that tells you what belongs to a gold coin and what doesn't:

```
gold_coins = hsv(:,:,1) < 0.25 & hsv(:,:,2) > 0.25;
```

We now get this image:

[image]

Not perfect.  We can see that the large masses of white belong to the gold coins while the ones that have holes in them are silver.

## Step #3

What we'll do next is fill in any holes that the gold objects will have to ensure you get all areas that are supposed to be gold.  Use [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) with the `'holes'` option to do so.

```
gold_coins_fill = imfill(gold_coins, 'holes');
```

We now get :

[image]

Great, but again we have the silver coins to deal with. The gold coins are perfectly fine.

## Step #4

To remove any masses that belong to silver coins, I remove all areas in the mask that have less than 12000 pixels.  This was done through trial and error.  You can use the function [`bwareaopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) and specify 12000 as the second parameter on this image to do so:

```
gold_coins_final = bwareaopen(gold_coins_fill, 12000);
```

We now get:

[image]

---

The full code if you just want to run this by copying and pasting is as shown:

```
% Step #1
close all;
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4FCV.jpg');
im_enhance = imadjust(im, [], [], 1.5);

% Step #2
hsv = rgb2hsv(im2double(im_enhance));   
gold_coins = hsv(:,:,1) < 0.25 & hsv(:,:,2) > 0.25;

% Step #3
gold_coins_fill = imfill(gold_coins, 'holes');

% Step #4
gold_coins_final = bwareaopen(gold_coins_fill, 12000);
imshow(gold_coins_final);
```

Comment: Rayreng! Thanks a lot Dude! Your approaches  works! I test with plenty pictures with some modification. And its works! Thanks a lot dude..!

Answer (score -1):

Using imagemagick library:

Fuzz operator will let you compare image color to a certain color.  While they won't have to be exactly the same but with a similarity factor you decide.  So the algorithm can be the following:

1. Detect gold color in the image (fuzzy detection)
2. Replace all gold pixels with black color (can be any color)
3. Count black pixels in the new image
4. If at least 80% of the pixels have been counted , it is a gold coin , else its not a gold coin:

Converting gold color to black:

```
 convert img -fuzz 80%  -fill black -opaque gold  newImage
```

Getting all different colors counts:

```
convert  newimage -define histogram:unique-colors=true \
        -format %c histogram:info:-
```

If the black count was above 80% (+-), then it is a gold coin.

<sup>*Be sure to select a replacement color that cannot be in the original image.</sup>

Comment: This is not a MATLAB answer.

Comment: Because that's not MATLAB syntax by a long shot.

Comment: Point I'd that op hopes for a Matlab solution that she/he can hand in. However, this is a site about DSP, so I don't think the fact that this answer doesn't use Matlab is the least of a problem - it describes a DSP approach and even illustrates it. A clearly useful, valuable answer.

Comment: So I really don't see why this got a down vote.

Comment: @MarcusMüller StackOverflow is not  a site about DSP. The site for DSP is: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/